# How to toggle Fusion Tables layer on/off based on map scale?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

In the Google Maps API v3 I'm displaying points derived from a Fusion Table by specifying a [FusionTablesLayer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#FusionTablesLayer)

Is it possible to set a minimum/maximum scale on this layer, so it turns off when zooming out?

EDIT: I'm presuming that I'll need to listen to the map's zoom_changed event, and handle the visibility manually. **But how can I change the visibility of a Fusion Tables layer?**

A **marker** has the boolean property [Visible](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions) and the method SetVisible() but I can't see an equivalent for a layer.

An **overlay** can have [show/hide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#HideShow) methods - do I need to build my Fusion Tables layer as an overlay? (I'm a Google Maps novice so I don't know much about overlays vs layers)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work - it doesn't seem to be a problem to call setMap if it's already set:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel >= minZoomLevel) {
        FTlayer.setMap(map);
    } else {
        FTlayer.setMap(null);
    }
});
```

Thanks to Chris Broadfoot from the GM team for this tip.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this.

https://sites.google.com/site/wildcardstestsite/home
Check out the xml file which in this case is used in a blog as a module. use the html and javascript of this file and you have a working example of 2 layers on and off capabilities.
Also I need to point out that only 5 fusion tables layers can be uses due to google limitations. I have not tried it with more in the javascript code to see what happens but I'm pretty sure if you add more than 5 on the list the 6th won't appear.

So it would be a great thing to add a limitation in the list. You could have for example 10 layers but only 5 can be loaded every time.

Hope this helps because it sure helped me.

Comment: that's a great resource - thanks very much for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Layer Control

```
    function updateHeatmap() {
  var heatmap = document.getElementById('heatmap');
  layer.setOptions({
    heatmap: {
      enabled: heatmap.checked
    }
  });
```

Official Example with code:
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/heatmap.html

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to toggle the layer between points/heatmap, not to toggle visibility? see [FusionTablesLayerOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#FusionTablesLayerOptions)